# How to get last request from mock?

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I have groovy spript in test step, and MockOperation in MockService. 
How to get last request in script?

Now I can check only time of last mock request:

```
def project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project
def mock =  testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.mockServices["mock"]
def service =  mock.getMockOperationByName("service")
def req = service.getLastMockResult()
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

For a specific response, you really need to clarify a few things.

In your description, you describe you want "last request". In your code, you do "getLastMockResult". Do you want the last request or the last response?

Is it SOAP or REST?

You also make use of "mockIss". Where does that come from? Is just a typo, and really you mean the "mock" from the previous line?

On a more generic note, given this is a SOAP request, and the Groovy Script teststep is situated in the same testcase as the Soap Request teststep, you should be able to do something like this:

```
def request = context.expand( '${Name of Soap Request teststep#Request#declare namespace soap=\'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\'; //soap:Envelope[1]}' )
def response = context.expand( '${Name of Soap Request teststep#Response#declare namespace soap=\'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\'; //soap:Envelope[1]}' )
log.info request
log.info response
```

Comment: It is SOAP. 

Yes, it's just a typo, I edited my post.

I want xml from request sended to MockService.